# Lighttable Autocompletion/ Suggestions not working in Mac OS 10.0

Tags: macos, lighttable

The suggestions dropdown available via the tab key seems not to work in version 0.8.1 in Mac OS 10.10. On other OS it works fine.

No special behaviors or customizations have been done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the problem was the "clj-light-refactor". After uninstalling / disabling it, the inline proposals were available as assumed.